# How to save the content of a udp packet to a struct, and print it

Tags: c, struct, udp, packet

I have the following struct :

```
typedef struct packet {
  char magic[1];
  char version[1];
  char body_length[2];
  char body[1020];
} packet;
```

Because there's an external protocol in place between all the peers that we have to respect, I know the udp packet I'll receive will be 1024 bytes, hence the arbitrary char array lengths.

This is what I'm doing when I receive a packet:

```
struct paquet reply_packet;
rc = recvfrom(s,&reply_packet,sizeof(reply_packet),0,NULL,NULL);
displayPacket(reply_packet);
```

How I display it:

```
void displayPacket (struct paquet p){
  printf("Magic : %s\n",p.magic);
  printf("Version : %s\n",p.version);
  printf("Body Length: %s\n",p.body_length);
  printf("Body : %s\n",p.body);
}
```

However, this is the output I have, if I'm not mistaken it seems like it's ASCII maybe? This is not the expected output.

```
Magic : _�▒
Version : �▒
Body Length: �▒
Body : ▒
```

But when I try to print the magic for example:

```
printf("Magic Test : %d\n",reply_packet.magic[0]);

Magic Test : 95
```

This is the expected output, Version would be 1, and it's 1 when I print it with the precedent printf, however I'm still unsure how I would be able to print the body... I thought about the fact that there might not a null terminator, causing that garbage ASCII output.

What could I do please?

Thanks

Comment: Are the data in the structure really ***null-terminated strings***? You should probably be using other types for the `magic`, `version` and `body_length` members (like e.g. `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`), and then use the correct format to print (like e.g. `%hhu` and `%hu`).

Comment: The one in my own structure? I'd say no, the magic is size 1, so there's no place for '\0', I thought about. But I left it this way because I thought: Let's say we have ```char magic[2]```, I receive the packet, put it in the structure, ```magic[0] = 95 now```, but what about the version number? Will it be put in ```magic[1]``` or ```version[0]``` ?

Comment: If it's not strings, then why do you attempt to print it as strings using the `%s` format? You say yourself that when you use `%d` you get the correct output so why don't you use that? Arbitrary binary data can't be printed as characters or strings.

Comment: Indeed, I guess I just spent too much time trying to sort this out and couldn't think clearly! It works perfectly with ```uint8_t``` and ```uint16_t``` Gotta deserialize the body now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StandardRight Take care using `uint16_t` as you may run into endianess problems

Comment: @4386427 I used ntohs to fix the endianess problem!